# Communication between Java and Python using Jython

Tags: java, jython, jython-2.5

I'm still trying to figure out how to receive a response from python script to my Java file making use of Jython. I know we can use PythonInterpreter execfile to execute python scripts but does PythonInterpreter allows us to receive the respone from the script ?

I know the question is being asked many times, but I would like to know if we can do this using Jython.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't done any jython, but I would expect you to be able to get the output from an interpreter launching in java.  Did you try reading from the system in?

Comment: I think you might be referring to(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861024/calling-python-script-from-java-using-runtime-getruntime-exec, this is without using jython, that's not what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

How about communicating through web service? It keeps modules loosely coupled and gives you ability to split work between developers more easily.

Comment: Using web service would do the trick, I can't disagree on that, but for a small task like (sending parameters & receiving response) , I think web service is a complicate way of achieving it.